Error pushing package with sf (geos dependency) to github pages via pkgdown R
I am attempting to put a package on github pages. However, I keep having the same error when doing so.
Writing `articles/index.html`
Reading vignettes/PACKAGE_VIGNETTE.Rmd
Error in `.f()`:
! Failed to render
  'vignettes/PACKAGE_VIGNETTE.Rmd'.
✖ Quitting from lines 373-380 [Grid Based Samples]
  (VIGNETTE.Rmd)
Caused by error:
! st_concave_hull requires GEOS >= 3.11
Backtrace:

(note I made up the vignette names above to generalize the problem, if they do not match - that is not related to the error).
I am able to get the preview site and everything runs correctly (including the code associated with the error), this also passes rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck.
I have attempted two methods to bypass this problem.

Copy the system requirements from the sf package Description (which I did not expect to work, but...) into my packages Description.

A simple drop in replacement of the sf::st_concave_hull to the geos equivalent. However, this would require more work to switch over to, and I would prefer to not add on the package for a single function


Beyond these I have not had much luck finding solutions. Here Hadley mentions that sf can be skipped from certain tests due to how much other software is installed along with it. However I'm not certain if pkgdown::build_site() allows for this - I don't see how it would.
Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Perhaps this discussion sf issues 2287 gets things going in the right direction.

Good point Chris! I updated the R version in the Depends section of the DESCRIPTION, I also updated SystemRequirements to GEOS (>= 3.11.0). Unfortunately neither approach helped. Seems I may need to go open this as a question on GH.

In a terminal, what does geos-config --version 3.12.1 say for you?

What do you mean by "put a package on github pages"? Is that code running locally, or is it triggered by Github Actions?

Chris, I get 3.11.1 Usage: geos-config [OPTIONS] Options:...

Spacedman, I had the code code set up to run via github actions, but I've since then tried to switch it over so that it runs manually following these steps (#5). However, maybe I need to remove the R cmd check which is set up for automatic? Sorry if this isn't doesn't answer your question, it's my first time using pkgdown.

A solution was provided by @kadyb and Ezder. In order to make this work during github actions, a suitable source of geos and installation of sf from source will be required. This is taken care of by default for Mac and Windows, but some more work is needed for linux.
Within the: .github/worflows directory you will need to modify up to 2 files, one is used for building the pkgdown website, the other is for the tests.
the R-CMD-check.yaml will need to be edited to this:
# Workflow derived from https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2/examples
# Need help debugging build failures? Start at https://github.com/r-lib/actions#where-to-find-help
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master]

name: R-CMD-check.yaml

permissions: read-all

jobs:
  R-CMD-check:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}

    name: ${{ matrix.config.os }} (${{ matrix.config.r }})

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
          - {os: macos-latest,   r: 'release'}
          - {os: windows-latest, r: 'release'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,   r: 'devel', http-user-agent: 'release'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,   r: 'release'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,   r: 'oldrel-1'}

    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE: yes

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          r-version: ${{ matrix.config.r }}
          http-user-agent: ${{ matrix.config.http-user-agent }}
          use-public-rspm: true

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-packages: any::rcmdcheck
          needs: check
          
      - name: Update GEOS
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
          sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev

      - name: Commpile sf from source
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
        run: install.packages("sf", type = "source", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/")
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - uses: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v2
        with:
          upload-snapshots: true
          build_args: 'c("--no-manual","--compact-vignettes=gs+qpdf")'

and the pkgdown.yaml which will allow the website to render also needs to be updated:
# Workflow derived from https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2/examples
# Need help debugging build failures? Start at https://github.com/r-lib/actions#where-to-find-help
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master]
  release:
    types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:

name: pkgdown.yaml

permissions: read-all

jobs:
  pkgdown:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Only restrict concurrency for non-PR jobs
    concurrency:
      group: pkgdown-${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' || github.run_id }}
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          use-public-rspm: true

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-packages: any::pkgdown, local::.
          needs: website
          
      - name: Update GEOS
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
        run: |
          sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev

      - name: Commpile sf from source
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
        run: install.packages("sf", type = "source", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/")
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Build site
        run: pkgdown::build_site_github_pages(new_process = FALSE, install = FALSE)
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Deploy to GitHub pages 
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4.5.0
        with:
          clean: false
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: docs


What has happened with both is the addition of:
      - name: Update GEOS
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
        run: |
          sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev

      - name: Commpile sf from source
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
        run: install.packages("sf", type = "source", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/")
        shell: Rscript {0}


Which allows for a suitable GEOS installation and sf from source.
